# Обращение по имени name

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, input

Есть input с кодом

`<input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox_input" name="available.instore"></input>`

1. Каким образом можно обратиться по имени (name) к этому элементу в jquery? (знаю как можно обратиться по тегу, идентификатору или имени класса, но не знаю как можно обратиться по атрибуту с именем name)
2. То же самое - только на javascript

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjmo0wqs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правила ровно такие же, как если бы это писалось на *CSS*:

```js
// Js
// 1 вариант
let input = document.querySelector('input[name="available.instore"]');
console.log(input.value);

// 2 вариант
let input2 = document.getElementsByName("available.instore");
console.log(input2[0].value);

// Jquery
let $input = $('input[name="available.instore"]');
console.log($input.val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox_input" name="available.instore" value="hello">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let p = document.querySelector(`p[name="folder"`);
console.dir(p)
```

```html
<p name="folder"></p>
```